# Return JSON and redirect to other view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this problem, I need to return JSON and also redirect to other view. An external party will call my view and expect me to response in JSON format and also after I'm return response, I need to redirect to other view.

```
public ActionResult MBBDirectResponse(MBBModel model)
    {

        RedirectToAction("Index", "CorporateExercise", new { area = "Applicant" });
        return Json(mbb);
    }
```

I tried to do as code above but it not working. Really appreciate if you can help me on this . Thanks guys

Comment: What's `mbb` in your code as `Json` method parameter?

Comment: @D-Shih it absolutely does not matter... There is no way to return two responses from single request - there are plenty of questions about it.

Comment: Your action should return a single http response, it should **either** return `302` (redirect) or `200` with `Json` data in it. Only way is to put redirect url into Json and instruct client to redirect to that url.

Comment: This flow does not make sense, if they are requesting data you would respond with json. At that point you've already responded to the request and cannot respond with a redirect. You can maybe respond with json and a redirect url in the payload or a location header in the response. But at that point its up to them to redirect.